# Connection to SQL Server with qt

Tags: sql, qt

How can I connect to SQL Server with Qt ?

Comment: QT seem to have an ODBC driver which you can use to connect to mssql. Here's the relevant docs: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/sql-driver.html#qodbc-for-open-database-connectivity-odbc

Comment: Why is this *not* a question? There are only a few ways to connect to SQL Server from Qt and this question cannot be categorized as "difficult to tell what is being asked here".

Answer (score 7):

Qt supports ODBC, to connect to an odbc database using a `QSqlDatabase` you can use the following code

```
QString connectionTemplate = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;";

QString connectionString = connectionTemplate.arg(server).arg(dbName);
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", connectionName);

db.setDatabaseName(connectionString);
db.setUserName(user);
db.setPassword(password);

if (db.open())
{

}
else
{

}
```

Most or all of the QSql... classes return an error, it is a very good habit to always check that error.

If you built Qt from scratch you might have to enable the building of the odbc plugin

Comment: @HeraldScheirich, what does `connectionName` hold? Database name? Thanks!

Comment: `connectionName` is just an identifier when you call `addDatabase()` you can have multiple connections/databases open, `QSqlDatabase::database(connectionName)` can be used to retrieve the db with the given identifier

Comment: Hi, you if always the string connectio have the structure: "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;", or sometimes can change?

Comment: How do I install this MSSqlServer driver on users' pc without installing the entire MS SqlServer database? I find this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, you could also connect to a database using a DSN. In this example, a DSN named "Orders" is created and used.

```
//Load Odbc driver
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

//Set DSN
db.setDatabaseName("Orders");

//Connect to db
if(db.open())
{
    //Query
    QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
    model->setQuery("SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY Date DESC", db);

    //Display
    QTableView *view = new QTableView;
    view->setModel(model);
    view->show();
}
```