# Connecting to Azure SQL Server with Qt on Linux

Tags: c++, sql-server, linux, qt, azure

I am trying to connect to a Azure SQL Server database with Qt on Linux but I have  not could make it. I tried some like this: [Connection to SQL Server with qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060916/connection-to-sql-server-with-qt) but the connection is never opened.

My code is so simple:

```
QString connectionTemplate = "DRIVER={SQL SERVER};SERVER=%1;DATABASE=%2;";

QString connectionString = connectionTemplate.arg("tcp:my-database.database.windows.net,1433").arg("my-database");
for(int i = 0; i < QSqlDatabase::drivers().size(); i++) {
    qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers().at(i);
}

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");

db.setDatabaseName(connectionString);
db.setUserName("user@my-database");
db.setPassword("My password");
//db.setConnectOptions("Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;");
bool ok = false;
try {
    ok = db.open();
} catch(QException ex) {
    qDebug() << ex.what();
}

qDebug("%s=%d", "conexión abierta", ok);

 QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;

 QString query = "SELECT 1 AS test_col";
 model->setQuery(query, db);

 db.close();
```

I already have the QODB and QODBC3 drivers so I don't know why I am unable to make the connection.

Is some related to driver, Qt, Azure or similar?

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: Nope, not yet :(

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am doing and it works perfect for me: 
Note: connName is the connection name on which I am opening the database.

```
QString connectionString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
                           "Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;"
                           "Database=ABC;"
                           "Uid=aaa@xxx;"
                           "Pwd=***;"
                           "Encrypt=yes;"
                           "TrustServerCertificate=no;"
                           "Connection Timeout=30;";

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC", connName);
db.setDatabaseName(connectionString);

if (db.open())
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    QString error = db.lastError().text();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: how i can get connName for my Application

Comment: connName is the connection name that you provide when opening the database. Refer to the QSqlDatabase::addDatabase() function in Qt documentation.

Comment: i tried QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3"); and its working fine.